# Exclude Skype from Email Clients being showed up on Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to Exclude Skype when I am trying to fire an Intent and I am using Intent.Action_SEND_MULTIPLE instead of ACTION_SENDTO because I want to attach multiple attachments with that email client being launched.

public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
Button openEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    openEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    openEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //When I use ACTION_SENDTO, this code works fine for me.

                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                            Uri.fromParts("mailto", "abc@gmail.com", null));
                    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                            "EXTRA_SUBJECT");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                            "Send email..."));

                    //But when I use the same code just by changing Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE, None of the email clients show up.

                    Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                    send.setType("message/rfc822");
                    send.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EXTRA_SUBJECT");
                    send.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");
                    send.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[{"recipient@example.com"});
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send, "Send mail..."));

                }

            }.start();
        }
    });

}
```

Everything's working fine here but if a user has **Skype** installed in an Android Device, that shows up too and I want to exclude that.

I Understand that Skype also comes under rfc882 and it will show up when firing an Intent.

Is there any solution for that? 
I went through a lot of forms and solutions but its not working yet.
Little help will be really appreciated.